# Login fromAndroid : Api Key or Session Variables ,Which is better.?

Tags: php, android, authentication

I want to create a user login from android phone (at Server side: PHP & Mysql).

So which is the following best option?

**A)** User Login return a Json Contains a API key, this key will used to Authenticate user.

OR

**B)** User Login sets a Session Variable(s).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think First One is Better if User Login return a Json Contains a API key then You can Store it in Shared Preferences and use it in entire application and remove from Shared Preferences when You Logout.

Answer (score 2):

First one i.e. **a)User Login return a Json Contains a API key, this key will used to Authenticate user.** is a good way.

why not second one because when we talk about mobile application session variable is not a good way , it is for web applicaiton or websites.